# Burnitate "picture-frame-widget" tag

Tags: discussion, tags

Can we burnitate [picture-frame-widget](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/picture-frame-widget)?

Summary:

- four questions at all tagged with it,
- newest question five years old,
- oldest questions nine years old,
- **doesn't have user guidance**

Quick browse on all four questions suggests that the reasons for which this tag was created / used are unclear (at least to me). But I may be wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The oldest two of the four seem to have some relevance to Samsung devices of that era.  There probably was a widget of that name and the questions are valid.

The newest two of those four questions seem to have the tag added just because it was offered to the OP at the time of posting and they just went with it.

For the oldest two, the tag is probably still of use if people have those devices.  In this case there is no reason to delete the tag.
For the newest two, simply remove the tag as it is irrelevant.

Comment: This only treats the symptoms.  Until the tag has user guidance information, the problem is going to recur.